# Should there be an indicesWhere method on Scala's List class?

Tags: api, list, scala

Scala's List classes have `indexWhere` methods, which return a single index for a List element which matches the supplied predicate (or -1 if none exists).

I recently found myself wanting to gather *all* indices in a List which matched a given predicate, and found myself writing an expression like:

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter({case (elem, _) => p(elem)}).map({case (_, index) => index})
```

where `p` here is some predicate function for selecting matching elements. This seems a bit of an unwieldy expression for such a simple requirement (but I may be missing a trick or two).

I was half expecting to find an `indicesWhere` function on List which would allow me to write instead:

```
list.indicesWhere(p)
```

Should something like this be part of the Scala's List API, or is there a much simpler expression than what I've shown above for doing the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's a shorter expression that removes some of the syntactic noise you have in yours (modified to use Travis's suggestion):

```
list.zipWithIndex.collect { case (x, i) if p(x) => i }
```

Or alternatively:

```
for ((x,i) <- list.zipWithIndex if p(x)) yield i
```

But if you use this frequently, you should just add it as an implicit method:

```
class EnrichedWithIndicesWhere[T, CC[X] <: Seq[X]](xs: CC[T]) {
  def indicesWhere(p: T => Boolean)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], Int, CC[Int]]): CC[Int] = {
    val b = bf()
    for ((x, i) <- xs.zipWithIndex if p(x)) b += i
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def enrichWithIndicesWhere[T, CC[X] <: Seq[X]](xs: CC[T]) = new EnrichedWithIndicesWhere(xs)

val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
def p(i: Int) = i % 2 == 1
list.indicesWhere(p)         // List(0, 2, 4)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the helpful answer. The question remains though, should this function really be included as part of the Scala collection API? Notwithstanding the implicit method workaround, this still seems to me to be a somewhat non-intuitive expression for a fairly fundamental operation.

Comment: @Henry: Scala is open source, feel free to create an issue for the issue tracker, write the implementation and tests, provide documentation for the change and raise a pull request on GitHub. What else do you want to hear? Often it doesn't matter if something is useful when there is no one doing the work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use unzip to replace the map:

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter({case (elem, _) => p(elem)}).unzip._2
```

Comment: Or (more concisely and potentially more efficiently): `list.zipWithIndex.collect { case (e, i) if p(e) => i }`